# Access "outer row" value in an analytic expression

Tags: oracle, analytic-functions

I would like to access the value of the "current row" on which I write the analytic expression on. For example, given the following sample data:

```
DROP TABLE emp PURGE;

CREATE TABLE emp (
  empno    NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT pk_emp PRIMARY KEY,
  ename    VARCHAR2(10),
  job      VARCHAR2(9),
  mgr      NUMBER(4),
  hiredate DATE,
  sal      NUMBER(7,2),
  comm     NUMBER(7,2),
  deptno   NUMBER(2)
);

INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7369,'SMITH','CLERK',7902,to_date('17-12-1980','dd-mm-yyyy'),800,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7499,'ALLEN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('20-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1600,300,30);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7521,'WARD','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('22-2-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1250,500,30);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7566,'JONES','MANAGER',7839,to_date('2-4-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2975,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7654,'MARTIN','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('28-9-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1250,1400,30);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7698,'BLAKE','MANAGER',7839,to_date('1-5-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2850,NULL,30);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7782,'CLARK','MANAGER',7839,to_date('9-6-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),2450,NULL,10);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7788,'SCOTT','ANALYST',7566,to_date('13-7-87','dd-mm-rr')-85,3000,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7839,'KING','PRESIDENT',NULL,to_date('17-11-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),5000,NULL,10);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7844,'TURNER','SALESMAN',7698,to_date('8-9-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),1500,0,30);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7876,'ADAMS','CLERK',7788,to_date('13-7-87', 'dd-mm-rr')-51,1100,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7900,'JAMES','CLERK',7698,to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),950,NULL,30);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7902,'FORD','ANALYST',7566,to_date('3-12-1981','dd-mm-yyyy'),3000,NULL,20);
INSERT INTO emp VALUES (7934,'MILLER','CLERK',7782,to_date('23-1-1982','dd-mm-yyyy'),1300,NULL,10);
COMMIT;
```

Let's say I would like to calculate the average (using the `deptno` for partitioning) only if the salary is smaller than the salary value of the "outer row"

Here is the query that calculates the average for everyone in the specific window, the row that is commented out what I would like to be able to do, "pseudocode".

```
SELECT t.empno, t.deptno, t.sal
  ,AVG(t.sal) OVER (PARTITION BY t.deptno) AS avg_dept_sal
  --,AVG(CASE WHEN t.sal < OUTER_VALUE(t.sal) THEN t.sal ELSE NULL END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.deptno) AS avg_dept_sal_2
  FROM emp t
;
```

So, while `avg_dept_sal` returns ~2916 for `deptno = 10`, for each row, with `avg_dept_sal_2` should return:

- `1300` for `empno = 7782`
- `1875` for `empno = 7839`
- `NULL` for `empno = 7934`

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `RANGE` window in the analytic function:

```sql
SELECT empno,
       deptno,
       sal,
       AVG(sal) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno) AS avg_dept_sal,
       AVG(sal) OVER (
         PARTITION BY deptno
         ORDER BY sal
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 0.01 PRECEDING
       ) AS avg_dept_sal_2
FROM   emp;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | EMPNO | DEPTNO | SAL | AVG_DEPT_SAL | AVG_DEPT_SAL_2 |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 7934 | 10 | 1300 | 2916.666666666666666666666666666666666667 | *null* |
> | 7782 | 10 | 2450 | 2916.666666666666666666666666666666666667 | 1300 |
> | 7839 | 10 | 5000 | 2916.666666666666666666666666666666666667 | 1875 |
> | 7369 | 20 | 800 | 2175 | *null* |
> | 7876 | 20 | 1100 | 2175 | 800 |
> | 7566 | 20 | 2975 | 2175 | 950 |
> | 7788 | 20 | 3000 | 2175 | 1625 |
> | 7902 | 20 | 3000 | 2175 | 1625 |
> | 7900 | 30 | 950 | 1566.666666666666666666666666666666666667 | *null* |
> | 7654 | 30 | 1250 | 1566.666666666666666666666666666666666667 | 950 |
> | 7521 | 30 | 1250 | 1566.666666666666666666666666666666666667 | 950 |
> | 7844 | 30 | 1500 | 1566.666666666666666666666666666666666667 | 1150 |
> | 7499 | 30 | 1600 | 1566.666666666666666666666666666666666667 | 1237.5 |
> | 7698 | 30 | 2850 | 1566.666666666666666666666666666666666667 | 1310 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=4a14167af671855e41a5f3060bba91da)*